# Client projection contains reference to constant expression of through instance method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

I am getting this error on my LINQ Code

> Client projection contains reference to constant expression of through instance method
> This could potentially cause memory leak. Consider making the method static so that it does not capture constant in the instance

```
histories = await _resourceContext.Histories
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.LmoId == request.LmoId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
    .Skip(fromPage).Take(request.PageSize)
    .Select(x => new HistoryDto
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        DateCreated = x.DateCreated.ToString(),
        CreatorName = GetAdvisorFullName(x.CreatedBy, cancellationToken)
    })
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

   private string GetAdvisorFullName(long advisorId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      var advisorDetails = _mediator.Send(new GetAdvisorQuery(advisorId), cancellationToken);
      string fullName = $"{advisorDetails.Result.FirstName} {advisorDetails.Result.LastName}";
      return fullName;
   }
```

I have tried

- By calling context directly in Query , it does not allows us because two contexts are not allowed in one call
- Converting it first into a Queryable then listing
- Made Get method async
- If I make this method static then mediator call gives error

Comment: I would highly recommend to collect all the `advisorId`'s and perform some batch querying after the `ToListAsync` and fill the data "outside" of the EF.

Comment: `histories.ForEach(x =>
                            {
                                x.CreatorName = GetAdvisorFullName(x.CreatedBy, cancellationToken);
                            });` This one worked

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move the call outside the query:

```cs
histories = await _resourceContext.Histories
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.LmoId == request.LmoId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
    .Skip(fromPage).Take(request.PageSize)
    .Select(x => new HistoryDto
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        DateCreated = x.DateCreated.ToString()
    })
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

foreach(var history in histories)
{
     history.CreatorName = GetAdvisorFullName(x.CreatedBy, cancellationToken);
}
```

Also note that it would be better to create a version of `GetAdvisorFullName` which will get all the names in batch.

Comment: Getting all names in batch would bring extra work because then I need to map those name with Ids in my SELECT